# Failed to use firebase rules for my project in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm new here on the site. I have a problem with firebase that I do not know how to solve.

I have a collection that I want only registered users to be able to access, access the information there and update it.

This is the code I wrote down in the rules but it does not work for me, I do not know at all why.

This is the code:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
  match /conversations/{itemId}{

      allow read: if isSignedIn();

      allow create: if isSignedIn();

      allow update: if isSignedIn();

      // FUNCTIONS
      function isSignedIn() {
        return request.auth != null;
      }
  
    }
    
    match /users/{itemId}{

      allow read: if isSignedIn();

      allow create: if isSignedIn();

      allow update: if isSignedIn();

      // FUNCTIONS
      function isSignedIn() {
        return request.auth != null;
      }
  
    }

}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

I want a registered user to be able to access only the conversations collection, this is what I did, I checked if you are a registered user, you can, update the content, add the content and see the content.

I tried to access the firebase documentation, but I did not understand anything that could explain how to fix the problem

I use firebase in react, this is the code I use:

firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default firebase;
```

functions that i use to access to firebase:

```
export const getRealtimeUsers = (handle) => {

    return async (dispatch) => {
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        const unsubscribe = db.collection("users")
            .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                db.collection('friends')
                    .get()
                    .then((data) => {
                        let friends = [];
                        data.forEach((doc) => {
                            if (doc.data().isFriends) {
                                if (doc.data().userHandleReceive == handle) {
                                    friends.push(doc.data().userHandleSend);
                                }
                                else {
                                    friends.push(doc.data().userHandleReceive);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        const users = [];
                        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                            if (doc.data().handle != handle && (friends.indexOf(doc.data().handle) > -1) ) {
                                users.push(doc.data());
                            }
                        });
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.error(err);
                    });
            });
        return unsubscribe;
    }
}

export const updateMessage = (msgObj) => {

    return async dispatch => {

        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection('conversations')
            .add({
                ...msgObj,
                isView: false,
                createdAt: new Date()
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });

    }
}



export const getRealtimeConversations = (user) => {
    return async dispatch => {

        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection('conversations')
            .where('user_uid_1', 'in', [user.uid_1, user.uid_2])
            .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
            .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {

                const conversations = [];

                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    if (
                        (doc.data().user_uid_1 == user.uid_1 && doc.data().user_uid_2 == user.uid_2)
                        ||
                        (doc.data().user_uid_1 == user.uid_2 && doc.data().user_uid_2 == user.uid_1)
                    ) {
                        conversations.push(doc.data())
                    }

                });

                dispatch({
                    type: userConstants.GET_REALTIME_MESSAGES,
                    payload: { conversations }
                })
            })
    }
}
```

I think the problem is very small, I just can not understand what it is, I am new to all this.

I want to say I used these rules at first, and everything worked great, but the problem is that there is no security here

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you authenticate?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think so, I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes form the fact that you do

```
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }   // <--- THE PROBLEM
```

and with the last curly bracket you are excluding all the rules that come after.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }   // <--- THE PROBLEM

  // Any rule here is out of the match /databases/{database}/documents statement
  //and therefore is NOT taken into account

}
```

So the following will do the trick:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    match /conversations/{itemId}{

        allow read: if isSignedIn();

        allow create: if isSignedIn();

        allow update: if isSignedIn();

        // FUNCTIONS
        function isSignedIn() {
          return request.auth != null;
        }

      }

      match /users/{itemId}{

        allow read: if isSignedIn();

        allow create: if isSignedIn();

        allow update: if isSignedIn();

        // FUNCTIONS
        function isSignedIn() {
          return request.auth != null;
        }

      }
    
  }

}
```

---

Note that you have [overlapping match statements](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements) in your rules, since you use `match /{document=**}`  which maps to all documents in your database.

Since you have statements that allow the access to the `collections` and `users` document, the `match /{document=**} {allow read, write: if false;}` statement is not taken into account (i.e. it is overlapped by the other ones). I would suggest you totally remove this generic statement to avoid potential errors, e.g. you mistakenly modify it to true and then your database is totally opened.

---

Finally, note that the [Rules Playground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator) is usually of great help to identify such problems, see below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I changed the rules as you told me. I get the same error, I do not understand why, I get:  `Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Apparently you also have a collection `friends`. You need to write a rule for it.

Comment: Thanks, I also added the same rules for the friend, but it still does not work for me, I can not understand why, because I did everything right

Comment: What happens if you check the rules via the Rules Playground as shown at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: That's what I get, I think it's okay. But do not understand why does not work
https://prnt.sc/1136bhi

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there anything else I need to add for this to work for me?

Comment: If the Rules Playground is working, apparently you are not authenticating well in your script. Please, check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth)